# Why can't start Google Remote Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, chrome-remote-desktop

Also I have infinity loading at https://remotedesktop.google.com/access

System Ubuntu 20.04
(zh;sd h;fghdfghidfzghuid ghfdh pugzpoum ifdioug(for edit)
Logs:

```
Feb 19 09:41:01 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094101.848763:INFO:chromoting_host.cc(108)] Starting host
Feb 19 09:41:01 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094101.851095:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1137)] Policy sets host domains:
Feb 19 09:41:01 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094101.851123:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1240)] Policy does not require host username match.
Feb 19 09:41:01 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094101.851129:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1159)] Policy allows remote access connections: 1
Feb 19 09:41:01 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094101.851320:INFO:ftl_signaling_connector.cc(137)] Attempting to reconnect signaling.
Feb 19 09:41:03 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094103.048669:INFO:ftl_signaling_connector.cc(94)] Signaling connected. New JID: eed268b131894fa78cdcc0268abfebb5@chromoting.gserviceaccount.com/chromoti>Feb 19 09:41:03 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094103.048720:INFO:heartbeat_sender.cc(172)] Sending outgoing heartbeat.
Feb 19 09:41:03 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094103.378292:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(956)] Host ready to receive connections.
Feb 19 09:41:03 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:03,379:INFO:Host ready to receive connections.
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,048:INFO:wait() returned (1927242,139)
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,048:INFO:Session process terminated
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,149:INFO:Failure count for 'session' is now 1
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,149:INFO:Terminating X server
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927244]: [0219/094105.152972:ERROR:connection.cc(66)] X connection error received.
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,488:INFO:Terminating host
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,489:INFO:Failure count for 'X server' is now 0
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,489:INFO:Failure count for 'host' is now 0
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,489:INFO:Launching X server and X session.
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:05,518:INFO:Starting Xvfb on display :20
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927350]: xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":20".
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:06,027:INFO:X server is active.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:06,148:INFO:Launching X session: ['/bin/sh', '/etc/chrome-remote-desktop-session']
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:06,158:INFO:Launching host process
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:06,159:INFO:['/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop-host', '--host-config=-', '--audio-pipe-name=/home/ubuntu/.config/chrome>Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.258905:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(406)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.258987:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1776)] Starting host process: version 96.0.4664.9
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478209:INFO:file_host_settings.cc(31)] Host settings file /home/ubuntu/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/host#4790dcd5b0eb6c774388357f3e52ea98.setting>Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478483:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1344)] Policy does not require curtain-mode.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478497:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1267)] Policy enables NAT traversal.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478502:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1285)] Policy enables use of relay server.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478507:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1306)] Policy restricts UDP port range to: <no port range specified>
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478514:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1355)] Policy sets third-party token URLs: <no 3rd party auth config specified>
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478519:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1377)] Policy enables client pairing.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478524:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1393)] Policy enables security key auth.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478528:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1412)] Policy enables file transfer.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478532:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1435)] Policy enables user interface for non-curtained sessions.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478537:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1458)] Policy does not set a maximum session duration.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.478547:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(617)] Processing new host configuration.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.479442:INFO:chromoting_host.cc(108)] Starting host
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.549653:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1137)] Policy sets host domains:
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.549669:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1240)] Policy does not require host username match.
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.549674:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(1159)] Policy allows remote access connections: 1
Feb 19 09:41:06 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094106.549836:INFO:ftl_signaling_connector.cc(137)] Attempting to reconnect signaling.
Feb 19 09:41:07 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094107.950526:INFO:ftl_signaling_connector.cc(94)] Signaling connected. New JID: eed268b131894fa78cdcc0268abfebb5@chromoting.gserviceaccount.com/chromoti>Feb 19 09:41:07 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094107.954376:INFO:heartbeat_sender.cc(172)] Sending outgoing heartbeat.
Feb 19 09:41:08 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927382]: [0219/094108.249860:INFO:remoting_me2me_host.cc(956)] Host ready to receive connections.
Feb 19 09:41:08 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:08,250:INFO:Host ready to receive connections.
Feb 19 09:41:08 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:08,748:INFO:wait() returned (1927376,139)
Feb 19 09:41:08 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:08,749:INFO:Session process terminated
Feb 19 09:41:08 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927195]: 2022-02-19 09:41:08,755:INFO:Failure count for 'session' is now 2
lines 1-74
```

zh;sd h;fghdfghidfzghuid ghfdh pugzpoum ifdioug(for edit)

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Feb 19 09:41:05 instance-20210501-1727 chrome-remote-desktop[1927350]: xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":20".
```

tell you you do not have X server Display 20 on your desktop. Set it or configure it to use existing display. Also firewall on your computer can be the reason for this problem so you can open the port for display 20 (if its available on your computer.).

Comment: My apologies.
I downvoted because you mentioned the solution in concept, without presenting the commands or direction of how to reach the solution.

Comment: @Amanze, I add solution! W/o much more details about your OS, environment there is nothing I can tell more. **Set it or configure it to use existing display. Also firewall on your computer can be the reason for this problem.*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm removing the downvote